# Widget to immediately phone a specific contact?

Tags: app-widgets, contact-shortcut

I have a widget that places an icon of a specific contact on my home screen.
Whenever I touch it, the phone immediately dials that person.

Problem is - I already forgot what the widget is called (I'd like to install it on a new phone). Can you help me identify it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is HTC specific, but this is what I need to do to get a "direct dial" icon on my HTC desire.

1. Long press on where you want to add the icon
2. Hit 'Shortcut'
3. Hit 'Direct Dial'
4. Select the contact you want to use (if the contact has more than one number, you'll need to pick which one)

There should now be an icon that will have that contact's photo and a small phone symbol on the bottom right. If you hit the icon, you'll immediately dial the contact.

Comment: This is standard since Android 2.1 at least, probably earlier.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many 3rd-party apps and widgets that allow you to place "direct dial" type of widgets and/or shortcuts on the home screen.  Have you installed this from Android Market?  In that case you should be able to browse through your installed apps in Market -> My Apps section.  You can then look up each app's description to see if that's the one that gave you this functionality.